# What is the purpose of throwing an exception in accept() method?

Tags: android, rx-java2

What is the purpose of throwing an exception in `accept()` method?

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    /**
    * Consume the given value.
    * @param t the value
    * @throws Exception on error
    */
   void accept(@NonNull T t) throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to throw an exception.

It usually denotes that something has gone wrong, and specifies what and why.

Just incase it is unclear, the below is an interface method stating that it CAN throw an exception, so any method calls need to catch it. It does NOT mean it will always throw an exception.

```
void accept(@NonNull T t) throws Exception;
```

So what ever the accept method is doing, if it has issues carrying out it's task, it should/could throw an `Exception`.

Edit:

There are a few potential reasons to why it is a general `Exception` and not a more specific `Exception`.

1. It is possible that different exception types could occur, to which `Exception` covers them all.
2. They do not care specifically what type of `Exception` occurs within your implementation (could vastly vary on implementation).
3. The interface was written in a lazy manner so specific exceptions were not declared.

Comment: But why generic exception?